# airflow message kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, airflow

How can I display all messages that are in a kafka topic?
I execute this code and it reads as a consumer what the producer wrote down at the moment the dag is being executed, but what was recorded there already by the last work of the dag, only the current one does not show me

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow_provider_kafka.operators.consume_from_topic import ConsumeFromTopicOperator
from airflow_provider_kafka.operators.produce_to_topic import ProduceToTopicOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depend_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 7, 20),
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}


fruits_test = ["Apple", "Pear", "Peach", "Banana"]
def producer_function():
    for i in fruits_test:
        yield (json.dumps(i), json.dumps(i + i))



consumer_logger = logging.getLogger("airflow")
def consumer_function(message, prefix=None):
    key = json.loads(message.key())
    value = json.loads(message.value())
    consumer_logger.info(f"{prefix} {message.topic()} @ {message.offset()}; {key} : {value}")
    return


with DAG(
    "kafka_DAG",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="KafkaOperators",
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["Test_DAG"],
) as dag:

    t1 = ProduceToTopicOperator(
        task_id="produce_to_topic",
        topic="topictest",
        producer_function=producer_function,
        kafka_config={"bootstrap.servers": ":9092"},
    )


    t2 = ConsumeFromTopicOperator(
        task_id="consume_from_topic",
        topics=["topictest"],
        apply_function=consumer_function,
        apply_function_kwargs={"prefix": "consumed:::"},
        consumer_config={
            "bootstrap.servers": ":9092",
            "group.id": "test-consumer-group",
            "enable.auto.commit": False,
            "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
        },
        commit_cadence="end_of_batch",
        max_messages=10,
        max_batch_size=2,
    )
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is or what you're attempting to accomplish. Can you add more context ?

Comment: @dstorey I want to see as a consumer everything that was written in Kafka before by the producer, and not just the last iteration

Comment: if I execute this dug, I get only the last cycle recorded by the producer as cosumer, but I want to see all the cycles recorded by the producer, even if I comment out the producer, I get emptiness

Comment: the consumer is commiting offset after every second message it reads - you should use a different commit_cadence to "never" as documented here : https://github.com/astronomer/airflow-provider-kafka/blob/cdcadef8a8981ae8e3cf44b93a7f7a6e229396d2/airflow_provider_kafka/operators/consume_from_topic.py#L34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        task_id="consume_from_topic",
        topics=["topictest"],
        apply_function=consumer_function,
        apply_function_kwargs={"prefix": "consumed:::"},
        consumer_config={
            "bootstrap.servers": ":9092",
            "group.id": "test-consumer-group",
            "enable.auto.commit": False,
            "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
        },
        commit_cadence="never",
        max_messages=10,
        max_batch_size=2,
    )
```

You just need to make sure that the consumer isn't committing the offset ever. If you set "commit_cadence" to never, this consumer will run from the beginning of the log every time it executes.